# Special Character ( ' ) Issue in Passing Query String Back Slash is Automatically added ( \ ) before ( ' )

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string, parameter-passing

Goto : http://www.uszipcode.us/American%20Samoa/

Now select From Drop Down Box --- >

"Eastern" than from second box "Ituau" and from third "Fagasa"

Also Notice how it passes from URL as Query String

Now when You select Some of the Name which contains special character single quotes ( ' ) at that time it adding back slash before this special character single quotes ( ' )

for example now again goto  site Main Domain As above given

From Dropdown box now select in First Drop Down -- > 
First "Eastern" than from second box select "Sa'ole"   and You notice that this **"Sa'ole"** is converted to **"Sa\'ole"**

I am not getting why it upadding back slash before '  I think This is Because of HTACCESS . MY HTACCESS in /American Samoa/  folder is

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
rewritecond %{http_host} ^uszipcode.us [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.uszipcode.us/$1 [r=301,nc]
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteBase /American%20Samoa/
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{6})$ index.php?pin_no=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-#%@&\s]+)/?$ index.php?state=$1 [L,B]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-#%@&\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-#%@&\s]+)/?$ index.php?state=$1&district=$2 [B]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-#%@&\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-#%@&\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-#%@&\s]+)/?$ index.php?state=$1&district=$2&city=$3 [B]
```

Please help How can i Pass Value Using Query String in Which it Has special Character Single Quotes . Also note that this can be Multiple time in Single words Such as : **'tau'ua**

Comment: Didn't you already have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796461/issue-in-passing-special-character-in-query-string-of-php-using-htaccess-f

Comment: It is not due to your .htacess code but your PHP code is doing a redirect to `/American%20Samoa/Eastern` when drop-down is selected on  `/American%20Samoa/` after form post happens.